# Why $G/C_G(a) \leq G/\zeta(G)$ in this lemma?

Tags: group-theory

[image]

**My question:**

Could you please tell me why $G/C_G (a)\leq G/\zeta (G)$ in the last sentence? Here $\zeta (G)$ is the center of $G$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: From which text(book) this comes from?

Comment: @NickyHekster This comes from a paper.

Comment: Which one? URL?

Comment: @NickyHekster I put the rest of the proof. Thank you so much for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry, but the answer of Chris Custer is *not* correct. You have $\zeta(G) \subseteq C_G(a) \subseteq G$, and this only implies that $G/C_G(a) \cong (G/\zeta(G))/(C_G(a)/\zeta(G))$. Probably you need divisibility and locally finiteness along the line to show that $G/C_G(a)$ is isomorphic to a *direct summand* of $G/\zeta(G)$.

**Note added later** Aha! Now I see the full proof. So indeed the statement you are questioning is totally wrong. As I pointed out above, $G/C_G(a)$ is a *quotient* of a divisible group hence divisible. That is what is needed. And of course that a bounded divisible group is trivial. So thanks for adding the full proof and good question you asked! I already +1-ed your post.

Comment: I don't see this. The group ${\mathbb Z}[p^\infty]$ is locally finite and divisible, but none of its proper subgroups (which are finite cyclic groups $p$-groups) have complements.

Comment: Hmm, yes, I am trying to prove the lemma, $G/\zeta(G)$ is isomorphic to a sum of $\mathbb{Z}[p^{\infty}]$ ... I also do not think this direct summand is going to work.

Comment: On the other hand, $G/\zeta(G)$ locally cyclic implies $G$ is abelian.

Comment: Yes - it would be nice to see the rest of the proof of this lemma.

Comment: @DerekHolt I put the rest of the proof. Thank you for your help.

Comment: But what does it mean for a group to be bounded? I guess, since $t$ is constant, it means that $[G,a]$ has bounded exponent, which is not possible in a divisible group.

Comment: Yes I agree the terminology is not the best in the proof. For each $a$ the group $[G,a]$ has an exponent $t$ (depending on $a$) of course.

Comment: @M.Ramana Out of my own curiosity, in which journal has this been published?

Comment: @NickyHekster Thank you very much for your consideration and your exact proof. I completely understand it now. My problem was completely solved. Your very welcome. Thanks again both for your help and your +1-ed.

Comment: @NickyHekster This journal: Ukrainian Mathematical Journal.

Comment: You are welcome, please tick my answer as the preferred one (it gets a green check mark) as is the habit here on this site.

Comment: @NickyHekster Sure. Thank you so much.